# Calculating text width including space / kerning between characters using Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, canvas, text-width

I have troubles finding any resources that explain how to calculate the text width of a string with different kearning / space-between characters.

Textwidth can use the font size, font styles etc. but not space between characters? (Or kerning which I believe is *very* font specific, i.e. gives different pixel values depend on the font since characters since they can "overlap" more or less depending on the kerning/spacing value)

Comment: Do you output text with specific kerning using ExtTextOut or using other means?

Comment: Please provide some sample that shows textwidth failing.

Comment: How do you draw text with specific kerning settings? DirectWrite, GDI+? That same library/API sure has funtions for you. Or do you want to know the width of normal GDI text? Then Canvas.TextWidth will suffice.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz It is not that it is failing. It is that I need to calculate text width using different spacing between characters.

Comment: @MBo I do not see any options for defining space between characters with ExtTextOut? But if there was such a function that would allow me to also calculate the width that would solve my problem.

Comment: I think unless other have better advice - I will simply ignore kerning and then do my own calculations how wide text would be if there was X pixels between each character. (That won't help me draw it, but I actually do not need that for now.)

Comment: What you can't draw, 'TextWidth' surely can't measure. Nothing will be able to, for that matter..

Comment: I simply don't understand - you cannot draw text with extra spacing, but want to know it's width???

Comment: I need to calculate how much size text written in different fonts, styles, font-spacing will take. Hence, I don't *actually* need to draw it if there is a way to calculate it without drawing. (To be precise, I don't really care if I draw it or not, I just need to calculate it.)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Correct, but if no better solutions comes up, I can maybe approximate it. The closer I approximate the happier I will be :)

Comment: OK, one more time: What function will be used for text output? There is no 'abstract text drawing'.

Comment: I need to calculate/approximate how much space different short pices of text will take up horizontally if shown in a single line in different fonts, font-size, font-spacing. That is the requirement. I had a vague hope I could maybe find a function in WinAPI of Delphi I could use to approxmate above *including* text spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Recommended reading: [Feng Yuan "Windows Graphics Programming"](http://www.fengyuan.com/)

Example of TextWidth (GetTextExtentPoint32) and more complex method:

```
var
  Len, w: Integer;
  s: string;
  GR: TGCPResults;
begin
  Canvas.Font.Size := 14;
  s := 'A simple test string';
  Canvas.TextOut(0, 0, s);
  w := Canvas.TextWidth(s);
  Canvas.MoveTo(w, 0);
  Canvas.LineTo(w, 30);

  SetTextCharacterExtra(Canvas.Handle, 5);
  Canvas.TextOut(0, 30, s);
  w := Canvas.TextWidth(s);
  Canvas.MoveTo(w, 30);
  Canvas.LineTo(w, 60);

  SetTextCharacterExtra(Canvas.Handle, 0);
  Len := Length(s);
  GR.lStructSize := sizeOf(GR);
  GetMem(GR.lpOutString, (Len + 1) * sizeOf(Char));
  GR.lpOrder := Nil;
  GetMem(GR.lpDx, (Len + 1) * sizeOf(Integer));
  GetMem(GR.lpCaretPos, (Len + 1) * sizeOf(Integer));
  GR.lpClass := Nil;
  GetMem(GR.lpGlyphs, (Len + 1) * sizeOf(UINT));
  GR.nGlyphs := Len;
  GR.nMaxFit := 0;

  w := GetCharacterPlacement(Canvas.Handle, PwideChar(s), Len, 0, GR,
    GCP_USEKERNING) and $FFFF;
  ExtTextOut(Canvas.Handle, 0, 60, ETO_GLYPH_INDEX, nil, PChar(GR.lpGlyphs),
    GR.nGlyphs, PINteger(GR.lpDx));
  Canvas.MoveTo(w, 60);
  Canvas.LineTo(w, 90);
  // free memory for GR members
```

Comment: There are some interesting functions there which I will look up and investigate further. Thanks :)